# How to check if album art is present?

Tags: java, android, imageview, uri, android-bitmap

I have an imageview **mAlbumArtLarge** which displays the album art of the song, but how can i check if the album art is not present and if it's not present show one of the images in my list.

**My code:**

```
private void loadAlbumArt(){

    Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
    Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, songList.get(songIndex).getAlbumID());

    int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image7 };

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(myImageList.length);

        try {

            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(albumArtUri);

            //Get the bitmap from the ImageView.
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

            //Let's apply Gaussian blur effect with radius "10.5" and set to ImageView.
            mAlbumArtLarge.setImageBitmap(new BlurUtil().blur(MainActivity.this, image, 10.5f));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to find album art", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

Displaying the blurred album art works, but if there is no album art i want to display a random image from myImageList.

How can i do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try get the id of the song first. According to your code i can't figure the structure of your data songList and it Index. But if it returns an int use this

```
    int id = songList.get(songIndex).getAlbumID();
if (id != null && id > 0)
{
Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, songList.get(songIndex).getAlbumID());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i'm not sure how to implement your code. The way i fetch my album art is with the id from the album MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID and then with Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
    Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, songList.get(songIndex).getAlbumID()); i get the uri.

Comment: But how can i check if there is not album art present ? how to check if the uri doesn't have an id for the album?

Comment: Log the value of sArtworkUri and albumArtUri and post it here

Comment: com.mp3player.mp3player.activities.MainActivity:                               ArtworkUri: content://media/external/audio/albumart
albumArtUri:  content://media/external/audio/albumart/3

Comment: The log for albumArtUri you can see id 3 which is the album ID

Comment: And what i want to achieve is to display a default image when there is no album art present/ no album id found.